# PostgreSQL row not shown when count is zero

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to output total number of orders placed by customers of each country in the year 2018. Here's my query:

```
select country, count(country) 
from customers, orders 
where customers.id = orders.id and orders.date >= '2018-01-01' and 
    orders.date <='2018-12-31' 
group by(country);
```

This prints out the correct values but countries with 0 orders are not outputted. I tried different types of joins as well (right join, left etc.) but still no luck. Anyone know how to fix this or know what might be wrong with it?

Comment: Tip of today: **Always** use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and _easier to convert to outer join_ if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use modern join not coma separated join, do  count for `orders.id`

```
select country, count(orders.id) 
from customers left join  orders 
on  customers.id = orders.id  and  orders.date >= '2018-01-01' and orders.date <='2018-12-31' 
group by country
```

You don't need parenthesis after group by

Comment: @tirth96 create table here in fiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8a150766c8bfab356b3cf1389684a11d it should work if not then you need to help us by creating fiddle then we can solve your problem

Comment: ok nvm this worked, do you know it can be done with just join, not left join

Comment: @tirth96 it will not work just by using join because with out left join you will loose the country from where still not ordered place

Comment: Is there a way to do it with nested queries?

Comment: @tirth96 why you make simple query nested query?

Comment: I'm still learning sql, so I thought it'd be nice to use a nested query to practice

Comment: That LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the orders.date conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Answer (score 2):

use `left join` and move your where condition in `ON` clause

```
select country, count(orders.id) 
from customers left join orders 
on customers.id = orders.id and orders.date >= '2018-01-01' and 
    orders.date <='2018-12-31' 
group by country
```

Comment: Tried that, still no luck

Comment: @tirth96: that should do exactly what you want. You need to [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55037647/edit) and provide some sample data and the expected output on that data. Or create a short online example, e.g. [here](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler) or [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Do you know how I can do the same thing with just join?

Comment: @tirth96, you've to use left join - with inner join it's not possible